# How can I add the value of a second variable to the name of one variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, variables, terminal

When i try create new variable with value in the another variables name in bash, I'm failing

```
]$ xxx=xxx
]$ echo $xxx
xxx

but when i try this:
]$ yyy_${xxx}=yyy
-bash: yyy_xxx=yyy: command not found
```

or

```
]$ yyy_$(${xxx})=yyy
-bash: xxx: command not found
```

or

```
]$ yyy_$(echo ${xxx})=yyy
-bash: yyy_xxx=yyy: command not found
```

Please tell me how can I solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved:

```
declare yyy_$(echo ${xxx})=yyy
```

or

```
declare yyy_$(${xxx})=yyy
```

it works!